# Read out all existing calendars to HashMap<String, String>

Tags: android, calendar

I try to read out all existing calendars.

I want have a HashMap with all titles, accounts in it. Can somebody help me please? This is my try. In the LogCat I see all calendars.

```
public HashMap<String, String> readCalendar(Context context) {

    String[] EVENT_PROJECTION = new String[] {                  
        Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,                  
        Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME                                   
    };

    Cursor managedCursor = null;
    HashMap<String, String> calendars = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Uri calendarUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        managedCursor = cr.query(calendarUri, EVENT_PROJECTION, null, null, null);

        if (managedCursor != null && managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {


            do {
                    // here I see all accounts and names in the LogCat

                for (int i = 0; i < managedCursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, managedCursor.getColumnName(i) + "="
                            + managedCursor.getString(i));

                }

                String title = managedCursor.xxxxxx;   // I don't know how
                String account = managedCursor.xxxxx;  // I don't know how


                calendars.put(title, account);

            } while (managedCursor.moveToNext());

            managedCursor.close();
        } else {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "No Calendars");
                }
 return calendars;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for column names in the Calendars table. They are [described in the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Calendars.html) (the Calendar Columns section). The calls might look like this (if these are columns you want):

```
String title = managedCursor.getString(managedCursor.getColumnIndex(
  CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME));
String account = managedCursor.getString(managedCursor.getColumnIndex(
  CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME));
```